# Can i change window border attribute in opencv, python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, border

I am working on some opencv thing.... switching webcam view <-> black full of nothing.

In image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH2hQ.png), black box is generated by (opencv)imread, gray one is generated by resizeWindow.

And the gray one (i'm not sure if i call that 'border', if you know better word, let me know.),
is the problem.

I want to control that area. Like changing color (black), or alignment.

What method should i use?

I am using python, opencv.

+) Oh, this image is just simple black box... but i want to use this code in webcam-border as well. So, i guess i cannot simply resizing images? because i don't want to make view more fatter or thinner.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "background". that color can't be configured. that color is hardcoded into `highgui/src/window_w32.cpp`. -- you should instead create your own GUI. tkinter would be acceptable but not very fast. GTK, Qt, pygame, SDL, kivy... are popular choices for GUIs.